# All errors in react-native crash get me stuck in xcode until I stop and rebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

It used to be that I would see syntax errors and the like in the iOS simulator. Now all of a sudden I get stuck in Xcode (see screenshot). I can fix the error, but pressing `cmd+r` in the simulator does nothing and I have to press `stop` in Xcode and re-launch the app. My chrome debug console is open.

The latest thing I changed that I believe caused this is upgrade react-native from 0.13.0 to 0.17.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are looking for but what is your active scheme? you can check right next to the stop button. It should show your project as the active scheme.

Comment: Yep my current project is there as the active scheme. Could this have something to do with my issue?

Comment: If it is the active scheme already then no, I had a similar issue and it turned out the scheme was changed by mistake. Sorry I could not be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem & it went away when I disabled my "all exceptions" breakpoint.